# How to return non-array JSON object from Apache Camel split?

Tags: java, apache-camel

With Apache Camel (spring-boot) there was a change in how split handled non-array JSON objects around version 3.13.

Is there any way to "force" the 3.12 behaviour of split? (or get a similar result?)

When splitting the following JSON document:

```json
{
  "listOfthings": [
    {
      "thingA": { "Afield1": "Avalue1","Afield2": "Avalue2"},
      "thingB": { "Bfield1": "Bvalue1","Bfield2": "Bvalue2"}
    },
    {
      "thingA": {"Afield1": "Avalue3","Afield2": "Avalue4"},
      "thingB": {"Bfield1": "Bvalue3","Bfield2": "Bvalue4"}
    }
  ]
}
```

In camel version 3.12, the following code:

```java
from("file://read/some/file.json")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
    .unmarshal().json()
    .split(simple("${body.get('listOfthings')}"))
      .split(simple("${body.get('thingA')}"))
      .bean("processBodyBean");
```

The body that would go to processBodyBean was

```
{ Afield1: "Avalue1", Afield2: "Avalue2" } 
{ Afield1: "Avalue3", Afield2: "Avalue4" }
```

in versions **after 3.12** the body contains the field level key-value pair.

```
Afield1: "Avalue1"
Afield2: "Avalue2"
Afield1: "Avalue3"
Afield2: "Avalue4"
```

The "new" behaviour feels logically more accurate - so i'm sure this is not a "bug".

We started with a new project using camel and it was deployed around the time 3.12 was released. We unfortunately wrote it based on the 3.12 behaviour. It's not a major re-write, but it is a significant change to a production system - which has run flawlessly for months.

We are just considering our options before we re-write.

Comment: It might help the reader if you try to mention your actual question earlier in the text body, and make it a little more clear in the title. It helps frame the mind while reading. Other than that, nice question!

Comment: Seems like something is missing from your example. You read from a file, which gets you an InputStream, then you're calling `${body.get...` on it. But there's no `get()` on an InputStream, or String if it's being type converted.

Comment: Sorry @JeremyRoss - The body is being converted to a string - the code wasnt intended to be functional - just illustrative of the change in behaviour.  I am doing a `.convertBodyTo(String.class)` in the actual version.

Comment: I'm still missing something here. Need to see how you're actually splitting.

Comment: We may have had some luck with using an AggregationStrategy on the split to assemble the object from its elements. I will post some code once we've ironed it out.